# Forward Emails to folders in IMAP

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with PostFix and DoveCot for mail in a VPS. I have figured out how to run them and succeeded in sending/receiving emails.

So far, I'm using the following approach: I have lot of domains, and one main principal domain. I created an account where all the emails sent to these domains (catch-all) forward to that principal (and only) account.

I have decided to use Folders to manage my domains, so for domain example.com, I create a folder called example. Everything is fine, however, I want to automate the process.

I want emails sent to something@domain.com, to be put automatically inside the domain folder. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the responsiblity of the local delivery agent to do this.  Common options are procmail and sieve.  For instance, in procmail:

```
* ^To:.*something@domain.com
example/
```

Answer (score 1):

Sieve is the way to go.

Dovecot has built in filtering capabilities. You just have to put your rules to the right place.

I think newer versions of dovecot even have managesieve protocol built in so you can use desktop sieve rule editor.

This is a standard solution with wide support.

Sieve desktop clients:
http://sieve.info/clients#desktop_clients

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, syntax is `mainaddr+subfolder@` and `mainaddr+subfolder.subsubfolder@`.

Comment: Only if your LDA is setup to do that.

Comment: No, it's not one's own LDA.  It's actually Postfix itself that one [sets up to do that](http://www.postfix.org./postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter), and it encompasses more than just `local`.

Answer (score 0):

If your "catch-all forwarding" is post-delivery forwarding (where messages are injected anew after delivery to the forwarding mailbox) or pre-delivery forwarding that rewrites the envelope recipient, then you have little choice but what M. womble describes.

However, if your forwarding is such that mail arrives at your machine *with the original envelope recipient mailbox unaltered*, as would be the case were this machine listed as the mailhost for all of these various domains, then what you are looking for is essentially provided out of the box with Postfix, as its [virtual mailbox domain](http://www.postfix.org./VIRTUAL_README.html#virtual_mailbox) mechanism.  All mail for, say, `OmarAbid@domain1.example` and `OmarAbid@domain2.example` can be directed to individual maildir storage areas, using the [virtual mailbox maps](http://www.postfix.org./postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_maps) database.

Simply match that up with individual maildirs for separate folders within a single Dovecot user account, and you'll get mail for `OmarAbid` within each domain sorted into individual folders.